# Android: Repeatedly create such xml Layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-ndk

I have to create the Layout (in xml or in java) as like Below image :

[image]

But it should be repeated as per the Condition.
Suppose, if the Arraylist.size() is more then 2 then the whole layout should be repeated as such time.
is it possible?

if yes then let me know how it is possible.

I want to create such layout in verticle direction of the linear layout.

Thanks.

**Edited:**
with jin35 answer i have done like this:

```
private void doCalculationForMultipleEmployee() {
    singleEmployee.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    for (int i = 0; i<=tempEmployerList.size()-1; i++) {     
        View repeatedLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.test);     
        ((TextView)repeatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_title)).setText("Employee"+i);     
        // customize repeatedLayout with other data     
        myLinearLayout.addChild(repeatedLayout); 
    }
}
```

But i got syntex error at .inflate and at .addChild
Please help me for that. 
Whats wrong with that ?

Comment: i am unable to see image

Comment: For example, you can make listview with child elements having layout you desire.

Comment: @Sver: ListView is not a good idea as i have to manage many data and variable. So it get somewhat complex to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create xml file with `LinearLayout` and another xml with you "repeating" layout. Then in code for every part of data just use this:

```
for (Employee e : employeeList) {
    View repeatedLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.your_repeated_layout);
    ((TextView)repeatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.employee_salary)).setText(e.getSalary())
    // customize repeatedLayout with other data
    yourLinearLayout.addChild(repeatedLayout);
}
```

Comment: Ok. So if i have Multiple employee and i want to display all the information of that employee. then should i able to show the every employee one by one with this one idea ? Means Employee 1 is first then below that Employee2 then Employee3.... and the information for every employee should be different. Is it possible ?

Comment: tell me one thing, a 2nd employee is displayed over the 1st Employee or below the 1st employee. as i want to saw the 1st and 2nd both employee if there are two employees in the list.

Comment: What kind of error do you have? I don't have eclipse now for testing code

Comment: i got error at .inflate like to add argument to match parent. and at myLinearLayout.addChild(repeatedLayout) as like to ass cast to LinearLayout. Please i need help for this.

Comment: in `inflate` method there should be parent - you can pass your linear layout, or null.

Comment: adding child allowed only for `ViewGroup`. So, just add cast to `ViewGroup` or `LinearLayout`

Comment: Please see my updated question. Where i am wrong ? I need your help. Plz help me budy.

Comment: So whats modification i have to do ?

Comment: My ParentLayout myLinearLayout is LinearLayout.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6606/discussion-between-idroid-explorer-and-jin35)

Comment: Please help me budy. Your answer is seems to correct but i got syntex error.

Answer (score 2):

why dont you try scroll view and embedd image and text view inside and link onCreate() using views methods (Layout onMeasure) : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html